# Perl, convert numerically-keyed hash to array

Tags: perl, hash, arrays

If I have a hash in Perl that contains complete and sequential integer mappings (ie, all keys from from 0 to n are mapped to something, no keys outside of this), is there a means of converting this to an Array?

I know I could iterate over the key/value pairs and place them into a new array, but something tells me there should be a built-in means of doing this.

Comment: **RANT WARNING!**  Why is everyone wanting to sort the keys?  There is no need to and it makes the algorithm so much slower!  Sorting is slow!  **runrig**'s answer is the best one here.  It will work if the hash is sparse.  Arrays maintain order but they are random access structures.  We aren't working with linked lists, people!

Comment: You're right: there is a way to do it built in.  See [Ether's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907270/perl-convert-hash-to-array/2907469#2907469). :)  This question is another reason why there's a difference between list context and arrays. Coupled with slices, it lets you do conversions between lists and hashes without any special magic or iteration, and imho is one of the most powerful features of Perl.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your original data source is a hash:

```
# first find the max key value, if you don't already know it:
use List::Util 'max';
my $maxkey = max keys %hash;

# get all the values, in order
my @array = @hash{0 .. $maxkey};
```

Or if your original data source is a hashref:

```
my $maxkey = max keys %$hashref;
my @array = @{$hashref}{0 .. $maxkey};
```

---

This is easy to test using this example:

```
my %hash;
@hash{0 .. 9} = ('a' .. 'j');

# insert code from above, and then print the result...
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%hash);
print Dumper(\@array);

$VAR1 = {
          '6' => 'g',
          '3' => 'd',
          '7' => 'h',
          '9' => 'j',
          '2' => 'c',
          '8' => 'i',
          '1' => 'b',
          '4' => 'e',
          '0' => 'a',
          '5' => 'f'
        };
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c',
          'd',
          'e',
          'f',
          'g',
          'h',
          'i',
          'j'
        ];
```

Comment: No `->` operator for the hashref?

Comment: @Zaid: nope, that's not how you use slices in hashrefs.

Comment: Silly me, it's getting cast as an array, which is why the arrow operator isn't needed.

Comment: No casting or arrays are involved. The *hash slice* returns a *list*.

Comment: And this will work even if the hash keys aren't numeric?

Comment: @AlexejMagura No. The code assumes the keys are integers starting from 0, which is how array indexes are numbered. If your keys are something else, it doesn't really make sense to use an array as the underlying structure.

Answer (score 24):

You can extract all the values from a hash with the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) function:

```
my @vals = values %hash;
```

If you want them in a particular order, then you can put the keys in the desired order and then take a [*hash slice*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) from that:

```
my @sorted_vals = @hash{sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash};
```

Answer (score 15):

OK, this is not very "built in" but works. It's also IMHO preferrable to any solution involving "sort" as it's faster.

```
map { $array[$_] = $hash{$_} } keys %hash; # Or use foreach instead of map
```

Otherwise, less efficient:

```
my @array = map { $hash{$_} } sort { $a<=>$b } keys %hash;
```

Comment: or to avoid map in void context: $array[$_] = $hash{$_} for keys %hash;

Comment: That'd have to be a `sort { $a <=> $b }`. Remember that `sort` defaults to string comparisons.

Comment: I'm not sure I see where I could avoid `sort`. That should be the case where I don't care about the order in the resulting array.

Answer (score 4):

Perl does not provide a built-in to solve your problem.

If you know that the keys cover a particular range `0..N`, you can leverage that fact:

```
my $n = keys(%hash) - 1;
my @keys_and_values = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } 0 .. $n;
my @just_values     = @hash{0 .. $n};
```

Comment: Or `my $n = $#{[keys %hash]}` if you have an aversion to constant-substraction...

Answer (score 2):

This will leave keys not defined in `%hashed_keys` as `undef`:

```
# if we're being nitpicky about when and how much memory
# is allocated for the array (for run-time optimization):
my @keys_arr = (undef) x scalar %hashed_keys;

@keys_arr[(keys %hashed_keys)] =
    @hashed_keys{(keys %hashed_keys)};
```

And, if you're using references:

```
@{$keys_arr}[(keys %{$hashed_keys})] = 
    @{$hashed_keys}{(keys %{$hashed_keys})};
```

Or, more dangerously, as it assumes what you said is true (it may not always be true … Just sayin'!):

```
@keys_arr = @hashed_keys{(sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hashed_keys)};
```

But this is sort of beside the point. If they were integer-indexed to begin with, why are they in a hash now?

Comment: Good use of slices. Also good point about initial choice of data structure.  Too bad you brought up `sort`, sort is slow (see my rant above) and error prone and is not desireable.

Comment: @daotoad - The first (and recommended) solution does not use `sort`. But, I completely agree about `sort`; it generates up to n-squared arbitrary function calls per invocation [hint: this is terrible].

Answer (score 0):

As DVK said, there is no built in way, but this will do the trick:

```
my @array = map {$hash{$_}} sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hash;
```

or this:

```
my @array;

keys %hash;

while (my ($k, $v) = each %hash) {
    $array[$k] = $v
}
```

benchmark to see which is faster, my guess would be the second.

Comment: Well the first is going to be O(NlogN) on average, but up to O(N^2).  The second method is simply O(N).  No need for benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Combining [FM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907270/perl-convert-hash-to-array/2907449#2907449)'s and [Ether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907270/perl-convert-hash-to-array/2907469#2907469)'s answers allows one to avoid defining an otherwise unnecessary scalar:

```
my @array = @hash{ 0 .. $#{[ keys %hash ]} };
```

The neat thing is that unlike with the [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) approach, `$#` works above even in the unlikely event that the default index of the first element, [`$[`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), is non-zero.

Of course, that would mean writing something silly and obfuscated like so:

```
my @array = @hash{ $[ .. $#{[ keys %hash ]} };   # Not recommended
```

But then there is always the *remote chance* that someone needs it somewhere (*wince*)...

Answer (score 0):

```
@a = @h{sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Hash_value = 
{
'54' => 'abc',
'55' => 'def',
'56' => 'test',
};
while (my ($key,$value) = each %{$Hash_value})
{
 print "\n $key > $value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a while as below:

```
$j =0;
while(($a1,$b1)=each(%hash1)){
    $arr[$j][0] = $a1;
    ($arr[$j][1],$arr[$j][2],$arr[$j][3],$arr[$j][4],$arr[$j][5],$arr[$j][6]) = values($b1);
    $j++;
}
```

$a1 contains the key and
$b1 contains the values
In the above example i have Hash of array and the array contains 6 elements.

Comment: And what if the original hash contains 100 elements? Or if you don't know how many elements it contains?

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is to do `@array = %hash`

For example,

```
my %hash = (
    "0"  => "zero",
    "1" => "one",
    "2"  => "two",
    "3"  => "three",
    "4"  => "four",
    "5"  => "five",
    "6"  => "six",
    "7"  => "seven",
    "8"  => "eight",
    "9"  => "nine",
    "10"  => "ten",
);

my @array = %hash;
```

`print "@array";` would produce the following output,

> 3 three 9 nine 5 five 8 eight 2 two 4 four 1 one 10 ten 7 seven 0 zero
>   6 six