# Transforming hash keys to an array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a hash(%hash) with the following values

```
test0  something1
test1  something
test2  something
```

I need to build an array from the keys with the following elements

```
@test_array = part0_0 part1_0 part2_0
```

Basically, I have to take testx (key) and replace it as partx_0

Of course, I can easily create the array like the following

```
my @test_array;

foreach my $keys (keys %hash) {
    push(@test_array,$keys);
}
```

and I will get

```
@test_array = test0 test1 test2
```

but what I would like is to get  part0_0 instead of test0, part1_0 instead of test1 and part2_0 instead of test2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl, convert hash to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907270/perl-convert-hash-to-array)

Comment: This is not even close to an exact duplicate of the linked post, and the answers there wouldn't answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a good time to use the [non-destructive `/r` option for substitutions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer).

```
my @array = map s/^test(\d+)/part${1}_0/r, keys %a;
```

For perl versions that do not support `/r`:

```
my @array = map { s/^test(\d+)/part${1}_0/; $_ } keys %a:
```

Comment: Note: Only available in 5.14+

Comment: @ikegami Where do you look that up?

Comment: @TLP : [`perldoc perl5140delta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions)

Comment: @Zaid That's only good if you already know which version it came with, though... Like a phonebook that's sorted in numerical order. =P

Comment: @TLP : I sense a question coming along ;) ... go ahead and ask it before I do :)

Comment: @Zaid What, you want me to ask a Question-question? Nah, you go ahead.

Comment: @TLP : Looks like it been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2500892/133939

Comment: @Zaid Brian d foy and at least 5 others seem to think it's limited though.. I'm testing it now, but ppm doesn't seem to like downloading Perl::MinimumVersion.

Comment: `perl -MPerl::MinimumVersion -E'say Perl::MinimumVersion->new(\"s///r")->minimum_version'` prints `5.004`. Obviously it hasn't been updated to know about `/r` yet.

Answer (score 13):

why not do easier

```
my @array = ( keys %hash )
```

Comment: in some versions of Perl you'll receive a scalar ( saying how many keys you have )

Comment: is this an older or newer feature? That is, in "current" versions of Perl, which way does it work?

Answer (score 3):

```
my @a;
for (keys %hash) {
   push @a, 'part' . ( /^test([0-9]+)/ )[0] . '_0';
}
```

But that just begs for `map` to be used.

```
my @a =
   map { 'part' . ( /^test([0-9]+)/ )[0] . '_0' }
    keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @array = map { s/^.+([0-9]).*/part$1_0/g;split }  keys %hash;
```